# Mouse scroll simulation in selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

While scrapping a website i have to scroll a table which is made of many divs'.
I used the following code to make the scroll bar move to the end,

```
source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/div/div[103]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]") ### Scrollbar element

dest_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[4]/div/div[103]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/span") ### ▼ element
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
```

but the problem it happens very fast and the data in the table doesn't load properly. I tried to simulate mouse scroll with selenium - python functions but couldn't make it happen. Is there any solution to slow it or any other way other than using **pynput**(it can simulate mouse functions, but i have to physically place the cursor on the webpage)

While scrolling down it loads more table entries. I also tried using drag n drop by offset but the scrollbar doesn't move and it throws ***MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException***

Comment: Do you want to scroll page down to trigger XHR and load more table entries?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not familiar with XHR ,could you explain?
Also only mouse scroll or click n dragging the scrollbar works

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the element then you can use the javascript executor to scroll to the element. I am not sure if there are other solutions to scroll slowly but if your requirement is to scroll slowly to load all the data then you can try to scroll to any element, wait to load data then scroll to other element and repeat.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement scrollto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/div/div[103]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/span")); //Find element by xpath and store in variable "Element"     
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scrollto); //This will scroll the page till the element is found
```

Comment: Sorry i haven't updated you. When i ran the code it isn't throwing any error and in the UI the scroll function was not performing